# TagToTip() in jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip

I need to convert a website which uses TagToTip() of wz_tooltip.js. I tried to find a implementation of this method which uses jquery, but without luck.

TagToTip() ca be used like this:

```
<span onmouseover="TagToTip('foo-id')">.....</span>
<span id="foo-id" style="display: none">This is the content of the tooltip. 
It can contain any HTML</span>
```

Does anybody know how I can to this with jquery, or jquery-ui?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hiya if you are looking for JQuery ui equivalent the check out this implementation:

**demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5eKYt/ : with various kind of tooltips. another here: http://jsfiddle.net/8vC2k/

**ui wiki for tooltips:** http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12138112/Tooltip

**few ui demo repos here:** http://view.jqueryui.com/master/demos/tooltip/

Further this will be a good read: [JQuery Tools Tooltip VS JQuery UI Tooltip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895464/jquery-tools-tooltip-vs-jquery-ui-tooltip)

If you are not looking for something like this let me know will remove this post, :)

```
 $(_this).unbind('mouseover').bind('mouseover mouseout', function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (e.type == "mouseover") {
                        timer = setTimeout(function() {
                            createToolTip(_this);
                        }, o.hoverDelay);
                    } else {
                        window.clearTimeout(timer);
                        removeToolTip();
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: Which version of jquery-ui should I use for tooltips? According to the docs 1.9 should be used. There is no official 1.9 release available, only 1.9m7 from 2012-03-28.

Comment: Hiya I would recommend using the stable version: Latest stable release is 1.8.18, last legacy release (jQuery core 1.3.x compatible) is 1.7.3. **Link info:** http://wiki.jqueryui.com/w/page/12137947/FrontPage ; BUt having said that I would say go with the latest if you want to test some new features and you can always see the bug list and decide if you want to play around with any pre-release versions or not., cheers!

Comment: The stable release does not contain the tooltip file: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/1-8-stable/ui. Is it save to use jquery-ui 1.8 and just "cherry pick" the one file jquery.ui.tooltip.js from jquery-ui-master?

Comment: Answering my own sub-question: No, you can't use jquery.ui.tooltip with version 1.8 because it uses _bind() from widgets.

Comment: @guettli hiya, Lol :) saweet, also you can play around with jsfiddle to add the .js files and do proof of concept if you like, please see the first jsfiddle it use **1.8.5** I reckon, lemme know if you have any further questions bruv, ;) any who lemme know if this helped or I will delete this post, have a nice day ahead, cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I found that bootstrap2 has a tooltip plugin. I think I will use it: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips